# p2os TCP instead of serialport/usb

Tags: ros, pioneer, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to use the p2os stack to interface an Amigobot, which is an Adept MobileRobots (ActivMedia) robot. This robot uses ARIA as firmware, and so do Pioneer 2/Pioneer 3 (DX and AT).
According to http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20p2os a computer fixed to the robot is required. I was wondering if the p2os_driver also supports to connect via TCP to the robot instead of using a serial/usb interface.

In robot_params.h I could see these defines

```
/* conection stuff */ 
#define DEFAULT_P2OS_PORT "/dev/ttyS0" 
#define DEFAULT_P2OS_TCP_REMOTE_HOST "localhost" 
#define DEFAULT_P2OS_TCP_REMOTE_PORT 8101
```

I guess the DEFAULT_P2OS_TCP_REMOTE_HOST refers to the port where to publish messages? Is it possible to set the DEFAULT_P2OS_PORT to an ethernet interface?

I would like to run both nodes, p2os_driver and telop_keyboard on a laptop an have p2os_driver sending the commands to the ARIA firmware via wlan. Is this possible?

Thanks for any hints,

BR

EDIT:

Do you mean setting tcp_remote_host and use_tcp with rosparam set ? If so this didn't work for me. p2os still tries to establish a connection using the serial port.

rosparam set use_tcp true
rosparam set tcp_remote_host 192.168.1.15
rosparam set tcp_remote_port 8101

I have also tried to use ROSARIA, the ARIA Port to ROS. In RosAria.cpp I found this in the Setup routine

```
    int RosAriaNode::Setup()
{
  ArArgumentBuilder *args;
  args = new ArArgumentBuilder();

  size_t colon_pos = serial_port.find(":");
  if (colon_pos != std::string::npos)
  {
    args->add("-rh"); //pass robot's hostname/IP address to Aria
    args->add(serial_port.substr(0, colon_pos).c_str());
    args->add("-rrtp"); //pass robot's TCP port to Aria
    args->add(serial_port.substr(colon_pos+1).c_str());
  }
  else
  {
    args->add("-rp"); //pass robot's serial port to Aria
    args->add(serial_port.c_str());
  }
```

I tried to run RosAria using this command:

```
rosrun ROSARIA RosAria -rh '192.168.1.15' -rrtp '8101'
NonCritical Error: ARIA could not find where it is located.
[ INFO] [1350643787.727256660]: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
ArLog::init:  File(aria.log)     Verbose     Logging Time    Not also printing
setup failed...
```

Still Rosaria seems to ignore any arguments passed to it.

Do you have any clues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44791/p2os-tcp-instead-of-serialport/usb/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2012-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I haven't actually tried this yet with an Amigobot, but it looks like with the p2os driver you can set use_tcp to true, and change tcp_remote_host to the IP address of the Amigobot (see http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Wireless_ethernet-serial_bridge_device).

Reed

Adept MobileRobots

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2012-10-19**:
Thanks a lot for your advice!
Do you mean setting tcp_remote_host and use_tcp with **rosparam set** ? If so this didn't work for me. p2os still tries to establish a connection using the serial port. I have also tried to use ROSARIA:rosrun ROSARIA RosAria -rh '192.168.1.15' -rrtp '8101' without succe

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2012-10-23**:
I'll have to try that with p2os at some point. With RosAria, you would set the port parameter to 192.168.1.15:8101, e.g.: rosrun ROSARIA RosAria _port:=10.0.126.32:8101

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2012-10-26**:
Thanks that worked for RosAria. I found this also here http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA .